# Piped Arguments: echo "value1 value2" | command $1 $2

Tags: linux, curl, sed, command-line-arguments, xargs

I have used Sed to grab two interesting values. Now I want to send those two values as parameters to Curl. I have been successful piping Sed output to Curl with only 1 argument using xargs, however I am unable to use two arguments for one command.

> > echo "value1" "value2" | curl --data 'valA=**$1**&valB=**$2**' http://example.com

I am stuck in both theory and practice. I wasn't planning to use bash scripting.

[ I am running tshark, piping output to sed, and hoping to pipe that output to curl so as to record data in a remote DB. ]

Comment: In your example there is only one argument making it easy to use xargs again. Of course, you'll have to combine and format argument stream first (with sed for example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as you're not expecting to use valA and valB in future commands, you can use `read` to store the the whitespace-delimited output from your exiting commands:

```
$ echo foo bar | { read var1 var2 ; echo $var1 $var2 ; }
foo bar
```

Which means you can do:

```
echo "value1" "value2" | { read a b ; curl --data 'valA=$a&valB=$b' http://example.com ; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can get sed to output something like .csv (foo\tbar):

```
tshark | sed ... | parallel --colsep '\t' -q curl --data 'valA={1}&valB={2}' http://example.com
```

You can find more about GNU Parallel at: 
http://www.gnu.org/s/parallel/

Watch the intro video on 
http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL284C9FF2488BC6D1

Walk through the tutorial (man parallel_tutorial). Your command line will love you for it.

Answer (score 0):

Backticks sound like the best bet, if you can't run the sed twice (eg you're doing this on a live tshark stream):

```
curl --data $(printf "valA=%s&valB=%s" `tshark --whatever | sed -e whatever`)
```